# identifier "Node" is undefined in Linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

This is my program to insert linked lists and print them. I'm getting error in `void Insert(int x)` function where I point temp variable to a new node. The error its showing is `identifier "Node" is undefined`. What am I supposed to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct Node* head;  //global variable head

void Insert(int x){
    
    struct Node* temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=head;  //it is the same as temp->next=NULL
    head=temp;
    
}

void Print(){
    struct Node* temp = head;
    printf("List is: ");
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    head = NULL;   
    printf("How many numbers?\n");
    int n,i,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&x);
        Insert(x);   
        Print();    
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cast the `void*` returned by `malloc` to `Node*`, but there is no `Node` type.

Here:

```
struct Node* temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
//                ^^^^^^^
```

You also do not *need* to cast the return from `malloc`. Example:

```
struct Node* temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

If you'd like to use `Node` instead of `struct Node`, you can `typedef`ine it:

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next; // struct not needed because Node is `typedef`ined
};
```

You could then also do:

```
Node* temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

Comment: thank u so much!!

Comment: @naruto You are welcome! Glad it helped!

Answer (score -2):

its called forward declaration

```
struct Node;
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```